# Generate eventlog event upon failure

Tags: powershell

Trying to get a event log on a failure of an echo command with powershell

```
echo $null > d:\test.write
 if ($?.Status -eq $False) {
   Write-EventLog -LogName "Application" -Source "Drive Checker" -EntryType Error -Message "Touch file failed d:\test.write" -Category 1 -EventId 12 
}
```

Not sure what i'm missing to make this work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) `$?` is a boolean value that doesn't have a property `Status`, so the expression `$?.Status` evaluates to `$null`, which does not equal `$false`. Simply check the boolean value itself:

```
if (-not $?) {
  Write-EventLog ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to omit the `.Status` and only use `$?` in your if.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> echo $null > Z:\test.write
PS C:\Windows\system32> $?
True
```

[$? Contains the execution status of the last operation. It contains TRUE if the last operation succeeded and FALSE if it failed.](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-automatic-variables.html)